# How to plot Riemann intervals with density function in R?

Tags: r, plot

I would like to have Riemann intervals underneath the following plot in R,

```
x <- seq(0,1,0.01)

t <- dbeta(x,0.5,0.5)

plot(x,t, type='l')
```

I have tried with `hist()`, and `barplot()` but I have not succeeded yet.

Comment: Do you mean the Riemann *integral*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "Riemann intervals" you mean a partition of rectangles fitting under your curve and whose total area is an approximation of the integral of said curve, then it might be what you're looking for:

```
x <- seq(0,1,0.01)
t <- dbeta(x,0.5,0.5)
plot(x,t, type='l')
for(i in seq_along(x)[-1])rect(x[i-1],(t[i]+t[i-1])/2,x[i],0)
```